# How is a dangling pointer deduced in string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17

[This reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) states that the second example produces a dangling pointer. How is a dangling pointer created in the second expression but not in the first?

```
std::string_view good("a string literal");   // OK: "good" points to a static array
std::string_view bad("a temporary string"s); // "bad" holds a dangling pointer
```

Also, what is the character `s` after the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `s` there is a [user-defined literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) that produces a `std::string`.

The difference between the two lines is that the `good` one is a `string_view` pointing to a string literal, and string literals have static lifetime (they last for the whole problem). The `bad` one is a `string_view` pointing to a temporary `string`, and that temporary owns its data - so when the temporary is destroyed (at the end of the line) it takes its data with it, and we end up with `bad` pointing to destroyed memory.

Answer (score 3):

The `s` constructs a temporary `std::string` from the string literal. Once the execution reaches the semicolon, the temporary is destroyed and a dangling pointer is left in the `std::string`.

The `L` in front of the string literal creates a wide string. This is usually UTF-16 (Windows) or UTF-32 (Linux).